# No blog table in my first Mezzanine project on shared host

Tags: mysql, django, shared-hosting, dreamhost, mezzanine

I'm trying to use Mezzanine cms (3.1.4) in a shared hosting at Dreamhost. I successfully created my first blog entry but strangely enough, I don't find the table associated with this entry. Phpadmin page at Dreamhost does show my mezzanine database (named hamlet) but there are only 10 tables in it :

```
auth_group, auth_group_permissions,auth_permission, auth_user, auth_user_groups, auth_user_user_permissions
django_admin_log, django_content_type, django_migrations, django_session
```

No blog table. Does someone have an explanation for this?

EDIT: Steps I did:

-Entered in my virtual environment env.mez

-Created the passenger_wsgi.py file:

```
import sys, os
INTERP = "/home/geantbrun/opt/python-2.7.7/bin/python"
#INTERP is present twice so that the new python interpreter knows the actual executable path
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/mez')  #You must add your project here

sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/env.mez/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/env.mez/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine')
sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/env.mez/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "mez.settings"
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

-Created on Dreamhost panel the database hamlet

-Created my mezzanine-project (mez)

-Parameters set in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
    "NAME": "hamlet",
    "USER": "(myusername)",
    "PASSWORD": "(mypass)",
    "HOST": "mysql.geantbrun.com",
    "PORT": "3306",
}
```

}

-Static files collected

-Command syncdb :
    python manage.py syncdb

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_redirect
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table south_migrationhistory
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_comments
Creating table django_comment_flags

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (leave blank to use 'geantbrun'): 
Email address: 
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.

A site record is required.
Please enter the domain and optional port in the format 'domain:port'.
For example 'localhost:8000' or 'www.example.com'. 
Hit enter to use the default (127.0.0.1:8000): (mysite.com)

Creating default site record: mysite.com ... 

Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
   > mezzanine.boot
   > moderna
  > django.contrib.auth
  > django.contrib.contenttypes
  > django.contrib.redirects
  > django.contrib.sessions
  > django.contrib.sites
  > django.contrib.sitemaps
  > django.contrib.staticfiles
  > compressor
  > filebrowser_safe
  > south
  > django.contrib.admin
  > django.contrib.comments

 Not synced (use migrations):
  - mezzanine.conf
  - mezzanine.core
  - mezzanine.generic
  - mezzanine.blog
  - mezzanine.forms
  - mezzanine.pages
  - mezzanine.galleries
  - mezzanine.twitter
 (use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

-At this point, on Dreamhost panel, I see that 14 tables are now created in hamlet database (auth_, django_ and south_migrationhistory tables).

-Migrate command: python manage.py migrate

```
Running migrations for conf:
 - Migrating forwards to 0004_ssl_account_settings_rename.
 > conf:0001_initial
 > conf:0002_auto__add_field_setting_site
 > conf:0003_update_site_setting
 - Migration 'conf:0003_update_site_setting' is marked for no-dry-run.
 > conf:0004_ssl_account_settings_rename
 - Migration 'conf:0004_ssl_account_settings_rename' is marked for no-dry-run.
 - Loading initial data for conf.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for core:
 - Migrating forwards to 0006_initial.
 > core:0001_initial
(...other migrations)
 > core:0006_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE    "core_sitepermission" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "user_id" integer NOT NULL)
The error was: table "core_sitepermission" already exists
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

Error in migration: core:0006_initial

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
(...other traces)
  File "/home/geantbrun/mysite.com/env.mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 452, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "core_sitepermission" already exists
```

Note that file referred to at last line is .../backends/sqlite3/base.py. I realize that DATABASES parameter is maybe overridden by local_settings file. I removed the DATABASES parameter from local_settings and rerun the migrate command. Result:

```
Error in migration: core:0006_initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/home/geantbrun/mysite.com/env.mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
      return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
    File "/home/geantbrun/mysite.com/env.mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
      self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
    File "/home/geantbrun/mysite.com/env.mez/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
      raise errorclass, errorvalue
  django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'core_sitepermission' already exists")
```

No more mention to sqlite3 but same kind of error at the end ('core_sitepermission already exists'). Does the migrate command should be run with --fake parameter because the database is already created?

Comment: Have you tried running `python manage.py createdb` again to see if the database is created?

Comment: Tried it. Result: CommandError: Database already created, you probably want the syncdb or migrate command

Comment: I started a new project from scratch. I created the database on phpmyadmin and run in shell the createdb, syncdb and migrate commands (in this order). Everything seems fine at screen. But no tables are created in phpmyadmin. Also tried with migrate --fake. No more success.

Comment: What do the database settings look like in `local_settings.py`?

Comment: I have settings.py and local_settings.py. I set the database parameters in settings.py. Am I supposed to also set something in local_settings.py?

Comment: Try local_settings.py if you're using the dev server. You'll need to rerun the migrations and do sync.

Comment: Tried with local_settings: dev.(mydbname) does not work. Removed dev.: migrate command gives error (unknown command 'migrate'). I'll put in EDIT the steps I did. Do you see a problem?